# OpenVPN iroute - Packet Lost

Tags: openvpn

I'm trying to expose a network behind a windows client.

The VPN was working perfectly. I have peer to peer enable, so everyone could talk to everyone. I used ping to test all connections, and it worked.

To expose the network behind the client, i used iroute:

```
iroute 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

And it worked for a while, after some days (without change anything) it stopped working. So i can only assume the problem was already there. It just worked for some reason.

I can connect to the the network behind the client (sometimes) but I'm having a lot of dropped packets. I cannot ping most of the clients, but it's not consistent. Sometimes it work, some times it does not.

The only thing i can tell it changed, is the number of clients, it was 4, not it's 42. And there was an increase in traffic.

If i remove the iroute, all packets are delivered, but of course i cannot access the network behind the client.

Comment: It seems to be a TAP problem. The Windows client is a Windows 2012 Server. I used the same configuration on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine and at least for now everything is working perfectly (with the same configuration). I'll perform more tests and post the results. But for me, it's a TAP bug or misconfiguration. As i have this option, i'll use the linux machine.